# Is that possible to check mobile keypad is active using javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-website

I just want to know, is that possible to make an alert when mobile keypad is open/active.

Below image, in mobile browser while focus on the input field the keypad enables, i need to hide the cog behind the send button.

[Image Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmJhp.png)

Is there any possible solution to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use css :focus on the textbox and hide the cog

Comment: @Rishabh You can have the focus while having the keypad hidden....

Comment: Yes , can...But in mobile, while in focus we can hide the keypad just pressing the back arrow or down arrow. And still it remains focus

Comment: The keyboard is essentially part of the operating system, not the browser (it can appear in all kinds of apps, remember), so it's not natively detectable by javascript. Checking the screen size is a possibility as a proxy (i.e. the size of the browser window is reduced by the keyboard). Google shows lots of people have asked this or a similar question before: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mobile%20browser%20detect%20mobile%20keyboard and the solutions suggested are not perfect - e.g. problems if user changes screen orientation, and other issues